# How to find $n! \pmod{p}$ fast

Tags: number-theory, factorial

I'm looking for a way to find $n! \pmod{p}$ efficiently. I did it with simple for loop and moduling as we add the number

`result = (result*i)%p`

But $n$ can be up to $10^{11}$, so this is too slow. I was wondering if there is anyway to do this that doesn't require a loop.
**P is prime**

Comment: For large $n$ AND large $p$, there is no known efficient algorithm, otherwise we would have an efficient method for integer factorization.

Comment: ...and if $n>p$, then there's not much to talk about.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs i did already take that into consideration

Comment: @Peter let's hope other bright minds will have an answer thus both of us will be able to learn something new

Comment: If $n$ is smaller than $p$, but $p-n$ is small we can use the result of WIlson's theorem.

Comment: @Peter i'm not really gifted in math so could you please explain how we are going to use it?

Comment: See answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727962/fast-way-to-calculate-n-mod-m-where-m-is-prime

Comment: @Murad WIlson's theorem states that for every prime $p$, we have $(p-1)!\equiv -1\mod p$

Comment: @ChrisCulter thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, this isn't an answer, but let me explain why I think there isn't a fast method for that: Imagine we have an algorithm computing $r(n,m)=n! \% m$ quickly, for $n\ge\sqrt{m}$. If $m$ is composite, it has a factor $f\le\sqrt{m}$, and that factor would divide $n!$, and thus $r(n,m)$, and the gcd of $m$ and $r(n,m)$, i.e. we'd have a fast algorithm for factoring $m$.
This isn't strict, because it doesn't exlude the existence of an algorithm working only for prime $m$, and failing (without indicating a factor) otherwise.